# Cleartext remediation on Jenkins EKS to smtp

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, jenkins, smtp, amazon-eks

Please bare with me as I'm still a complete novice at Kubernetes. My organization is trying to clean up some findings, one being cleartext to smtp on port 25. The solution was enabling ssl/tls connection. My attempt to update the main.cf file on postfix was futile as I found out the hard way that jenkins uses the server to send out email notifications of build failures/success(caused build failures).

I've already generated a SSL and I know that you would normally keep it in key store for jenkins to auth into smtp server. With it being a pod execing into it and editing files would not suffice and this would need to be done at a higher level, but I'm unsure of how I can actually get the key onto Jenkins to use.

What is the best approach of trying to get this completed on a program that is deployed on a pod?

p.s I thought I could try to edit secrets but seems like its stored on api server which is managed by aws.